# Texture Painting a HDRI Background

Tags: texture-painting, hdri

I would like to texture paint a HDRI background for my projects.. The idea is to texture paint an image and then use it as an environment texture in the Shader for my World Object. I would like to be able to texture paint my own sky domes..

There is one Youtube video on this topic, but it's very unclear on how exactly to achieve this result..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8gsDJs8xWA

And a Twitter Message on this topic..
https://twitter.com/mathiaszamecki/status/1418230264942243843?lang=en

I would like to know if I can realise this in Blender..
If so, how exactly?
If not, what program do I use for this?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He paints a landscape on a sphere, at the end the image can be used as HDRI.

To do it, create a sphere (it will already be unwrapped by default), scale it a lot, like 60 times, give it a material with an *Image Texture* (the image needs to be 2:1, for example 2048 x 1024), paint the horizon on it:

[image]

Then flip the normals, switch to *Perspective* mode, put your point of view in the middle of the sphere, and paint again, this time you'll paint all the details (or just some of them, it may be more convenient to paint later in the *Image Editor*):

[image]

Once finished, open the *Image Editor* and paint all the parts that have been left unpainted, you can even rework your image, add details, etc:

[image]

Now you can use the same image as *Environment Texture* in the *World* material:

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots!! :-)